# if $g(t)=\int_0^tf(s)\,ds$ and $h:=e^{-g}$, does it hold $h(b)=h(a)-\int_a^bh(t)f(t)\:{\rm d}t$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be Borel measurable, $$g(t):=\int_0^tf(s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0$$ and $$h:=e^{-g}.$$

> Are we able to show that $$h(b)=h(a)-\int_a^bh(t)f(t)\:{\rm d}t\tag1$$ for all $b\ge a\ge0$?

If necessary, assume that $f$ is locally Lebesgue integrable or even continuous.

Comment: Why not applying the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity is not needed. Assume $f$ is locally integrable and restrict attention to a finite interval $[0,N]$. (You can then vary $N$). It then follows that $g$ is absolutely continuous with $g'=f$ a.e. This also implies that $h$ is absolutely continuous with $h'=-e^{-g}g'=-hf$ a.e. Hence, $h(b)-h(a)=\int_a^{b} h'(t)dt=-\int_a^{b} f(t)h(t)dt$.

Note: If $g$ is absolutely continuous and $\phi$ is Lipschitz then $\phi\circ g$ is absolutely continuous. Take $\phi (x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: But check $h'=-h f$

Comment: @ZAhmed Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can we still show the claim if $f$ is *not* locally Lebesgue integrable(, but nonnegative)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, you can apply the result to $\min \{f,n\}$ and then let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see. I think we need monotone convergence for that and hence it should be important that $x\mapsto-e^{-x}$ is nondecreasing, right? Otherwise the claim would not necessarily generalize if $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ where replaced by any $\varphi\in C^1([0,\infty))$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes that is right. When I said it works for non-negative $f$ I didn't mean that it holds for any $\phi$.